# how to join four table in msql?

Tags: php

```
create table area (
area_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
area_name varchar(60) not null,
primary key (area_id)
);

create table mainCategory(
mc_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
mc_name varchar(60) not null,
area_id int(11) not null,
primary key(mc_id),
foreign key(area_id) references area(area_id)
);

create table subCategory(
sc_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
sc_name varchar(60) not null,
mc_id int(11) not null,
area_id int(11) not null,
primary key(sc_id),
foreign key(mc_id) references mc(mc_id),
foreign key(area_id) references area(area_id)
);


create table shopes(
s_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
s_name varchar(60) not null,
s_address varchar(120) not null,
s_work varchar(255) not null,
s_imagepath varchar(255) not null,
s_image varchar(255) not null,
area_id int(11) not null,
mc_id int(11) not null,
sc_id int(11) not null,
primary key(s_id),
foreign key(area_id) references area(area_id),
foreign key(mc_id) references mc(mc_id),
foreign key(sc_id) references sc(sc_id)
);
```

I want to select data from four table with mysql join. I am using

```
select s_name,s_address,s_work,s_image,area_name,mc_name from shopes inner join area on area.area_id=shopes.area_id inner join mainCategory on mc.area_id=area.area_id;
```

It is a three table join and it is not giving appropriate result. It is giving repeated result.

Comment: Have you tried:`select s_name,s_address,s_work,s_image,area_name,mc_name from shopes inner join area on area.area_id=shopes.area_id inner join mainCategory on mc.area_id=area.area_id group by shopes.id;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select s.s_name, s.s_address, s.s_work, s.s_image, a.area_name, mc.mc_name  from shope as s LEFT JOIN area as a on a.area_id=s.area_id LEFT JOIN mainCategory as mc on mc.area_id=a.area_id LEFT JOIN subCategory as sc on sc.area_id=a.area_id
```

I have used LEFT JOIN keyword instead of inner join, it's returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax.

```
select a.coumn1, 
a.coumn2,
b.coumn1, 
c.coulumn1,
d.column1,
d.column2
from table1 a 
left outer join table2 b 
on a.id=b.id 
left outer join table3 c 
on b.id=c.id 
left outer join table4 d 
on a.id=d.id 
where a.name = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s_name, s_address, s_work, s_image, area_name, mc_name
from shopes, area, mainCategory
where shopes.area_id = area.area_id
and shopes.mc_id = mainCategory.mc_id;
```

If still got duplicate data, use:

```
select distinct s_name, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s_name,s_address,s_work,s_image,area_name,mc_name
  from area
 inner join area
    on area.area_id=shopes.area_id
 inner join mainCategory
    on mc.area_id=area.area_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.
select shopes.s_name,s_address,s_work,s_image, area.area_name, maincategory.mc_name from shopes join area on shopes.area_id=area.area_id
join maincategory on shopes.mc_id=maincategory.mc_id;